# User ID Soft Delete or Hard Delete?

Tags: deletion, account-security

Is there any particular reason (security) for us to implement Soft Delete Mechanism on Deleting User ID or Hard Delete.

I am trying to make my user id better for my web application

thank you.

Comment: If you hard delete, you've removed all the data, so it can't be taken if you get breached later on. If you soft delete, the data is still around, but marked as deactivated - it can still be taken. However, it's more of a business decision - if you allow people to reactivate accounts, and get back previous data, you can't hard delete.

Comment: If your system need to be audited, you might be required to be able to show that you keep records of users, user activities, and some of their data even when they're no longer active, to establish accountability.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, my vote would be to soft delete; but eliminate any sensitive data (such as password hashes).  As in line with with Matthew's comment;

1. **Accountability** : if find out in X amount of time that you were breached by a user whose contact details you don't have, will make it very difficult to find out what exactly happened. And even provide potential evidence, etc.
2. **Data scrubbing** : users re-use passwords, no matter what we tell them.  If your service does get compromised, you wouldn't want your customers' password hash to be exposed.

Probably a lot more engineering work, but potentially worth looking at.  De-activate accounts but keep a reference to them somewhere, so ensure you're not re-using the user ID.

Bottomline, there's very little gain by hard deleting user accounts.  Storage is virtually free, and unless it's a business / regulatory decision, it's better to keep the (scrubbed) account.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So nice to read all this. =O Mindblowing.